# Woocommerce - How can I add a link on Add to cart page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

I am using [woocommerce](http://www.woothemes.com/woocommerce/) to develop an ecommerce store.Everything is working fine. What I want to do is I want to add a link after add to cart button on single product page. basically I want to show user  a link name sizechart which shows a page or popup. below is the image
[image]

If anyone know any plugin of woo commerce which can do that or If it is possible by going into the code then please tell me.
THANks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following code in the plugin file or function.php file of the theme.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'fun_add_link_below', 50 );
function fun_add_link_below()
{
echo "<a href='#'>Link text</a>";
}
```

If the link displays above 'Add to cart' button, just decrease the priority of the function. Try setting it to 60 or 70.

We have created a plugin that uses the similar logic in WooCommerce. This plugin provides a button below the add to cart to make enquiries for products. You can view the demo here [Product Enquiry Pro for WooCommerce](http://wisdmlabs.com/woocommerce-product-enquiry-pro/)

Answer (score 0):

Go to /plugins/woocommerce/templates/ and copy the content-single-product.php file to /your-theme/woocommerce/

Then look for the line that says

```
    <div class="summary entry-summary">

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_single_product_summary hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
    ?>

</div><!-- .summary -->
```

Just paste your link code before the

```
</div><!-- .summary -->
```

but after

```
?>
```

Adjust as needed.